# How to implement greater than or less than query parameters for FastAPI

Tags: python, rest, fastapi

I'd like to build an endpoint that looks like `/cities?population__gt=100000` to get all cities with a population greater than 100,000.

What's the best way to do this in FastAPI? I'd prefer not to have to enumerate all the possible operators for a given field, likeso:

```py
@app.get("/cities")
def get_city(
    population: int = None,
    population_gt: int = None,
    population_gte: int = None,
    population_lt: int = None,
    population_lte: int = None):
    return ...
```

Comment: maybe you could get a body (json) where user can put : `"population" :{ "gt" : x, "lt": y} `  then make an array of functions pointers to set this up correctly. Then you can iterate over the operators and check `if kw in operators` operators being the à list of operators (gt, lt, gte, etc.) then you use a dict to call a function : `cities = operators[kw](cities, population)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to implement this is to pass the `operator` (i.e., `gt`, `lt`, etc), and have a separate function for each operation, which you can call if an operator is received. Example below. You can adjust/add functions as required.

```python
def gt(population):
    return f"operator: gt, population: {population}"
 
def gte(population):
    return f"operator: gte, population: {population}"
 
def lt(population):
    return f"operator: lt, population: {population}"

def lte(population):
    return f"operator: lte, population: {population}"
   
operators = {"gt": gt, "gte": gte, "lt": lt, "lte": lte}
   
@app.get("/cities")
def get_city(population: int = None, operator: str = None):
    if operator in operators:
        result = operators[operator](population)
        return result
    else:
        return "Operator Not Found!"
```

### Update

Since you mentioned that this needs to be done for more than one parameters, I would then suggest using an approach similar to [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cdfsp/7.6.1.2?topic=method-query-parameters-operators), where you could pass the operator within the value of each key and extract it later on server side, for example:

```
/cities?population=~gt~100000&population=~lt~500000&size=~eq~100000
```

You could have operators similar to the link above, i.e., "Equals": `~eq~`, "Greater than": `~gt~`, "Greater than equals": `~gteq~`, and so on.

To receive multiple values for a query parameter, such as the `population` in the example URL given above, in order to perform operations such as `where population is greater than <number> and less than <number>`, you could declare a query parameter with a type of `List` and explicitly use `Query`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845425/17865804) and explained in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values).

The below example provides the logic behind this approach using the `population` parameter, as well as shows how to extract the operator and the actual value on server side. It is then up to you to define the rest of the parameters needed, as well as how to handle these data; for example, using a similar approach to the one above (having a function for each operation), or constructing the query you are about to pass to your database as you loop through the data.

```py
import re
pattern = "~(.*?)~"
 
@app.get("/cities")
def get_city(population: List[str] = Query(None)):
    pop_qs = {}
    
    for p in population:
        try:
            pop_opr = re.search(pattern, p).group(1)
            pop_no_str = re.sub(r"^~.*?~", "", p)
        except:
            return "Invalid data received"
        try:
            pop_no = int(pop_no_str)
            pop_qs.update({pop_opr : pop_no})
        except ValueError:
            return f"Cannot convert '{pop_no_str}' to Integer."
            
    return pop_qs
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I should have clarified that ideally I'd like to be able to operate on an arbitrary number of fields--eg population, size, density, avg temp--so it would probably get unwieldy to have to pass an operator specific to each column

Comment: Thx @Chris--I think this looks good!