# FastAPI and list of structured objects in class in a GET request

Tags: fastapi

I have a GET request that accepts parameters that were defined as class dependencies like in the [FastAPI Docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/).

I already had a problem including a list of strings as a property of the dependency class, but I solved it.

However now I want a list of objects to be a property of the dependency class, but it seems that FastAPI cannot handle list of complex objects in such a situation.

Does anybody have an idea on how I can define something like the following and not having FastAPI about handling list of complex objects in GET requests?

This is an example that fails:

```py
class Foo(BaseModel):
  some_property:int
  list_of_objects:list(some_obj)

@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(commons: Annotated[Foo, Depends()]):
  ...
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71554017/17865804) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840850/17865804) answer your question?