# FastAPI process integers

Tags: python, fastapi

I have the following code

```
@app.get("/process_integers_url/")
async def process_integers_url(numbers: List[int] = None):

    if numbers is None:

        return {"error": "No numbers provided!"}    

    result_sum = sum(numbers)
    result_product = 1
    for num in numbers:
        result_product *= num
    return {
        "sum": result_sum,
        "product": result_product,
    }
```

I want to pass a list of parameters to the process_integers endpoint via the url.

However, when I use this URL
http://localhost:8000/process_integers/?numbers=1&numbers=2&numbers=3
, I always get the error "No numbers provided".

Can someone tell me why this is or how I can fix this problem?

Comment: What happens if you only give the parameter name once? I.e. http://localhost:8000/process_integers_url/?numbers=1,2,3

Comment: Related answers, in addition to the link provided at the top of this question, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73067473/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982479/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845425/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71554017/17865804)