# Can the path parameter be a list in fastapi?

Tags: fastapi

I am using fastapi to write Oracle database query interface, when I define the type of path parameter as list inside the function, the following error is reported,

[image]

can the path parameter be of list type?  If the path parameter can be a list type, how should it be defined?  If the path parameter cannot be a list, do I need to define the query parameter as a list type for the query?

My code is

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Body, status, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel, model_validator, HttpUrl
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from databases import Database
from typing import List, Optional, Union

cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"E:\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0\instantclient_12_1")

my_database_connection = "oracle+cx_oracle://super:4567@172.16.91.132:1521/adbc"

engine = create_engine(my_database_connection)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)


app = FastAPI()




@app.post("/multi_sn/{multi_sn}")
async def post_multisn(multi_sn: list):
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        sql = """ ... """.format(multi_sn,multi_sn,multi_sn,multi_sn)
        result = conn.execute(text(sql))
        return result.all()
```

Comment: What do expect a list in the path parameter to match? What's each element of the list supposed to be?

Comment: Do you need constant or variable count of elements in this list? Can you give the example of how the URL for this endpoint should look like?

Comment: In short, `Path` parameters can not be `list`s, but you can get it as one `str` parameter and parse in your code. But if you need constant amount of elements in this list, you can add several path parameters (with different names), e.g. `@app.post("/multi_sn/{multi_sn_1}/{multi_sn_2}/{multi_sn_3}")`

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71427592/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71554017/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982479/17865804)

Comment: A side comment: Since you're creating new code, you should use the latest version of cx_Oracle, which was renamed python-oracledb (nearly two years ago!), see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: You might also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72070110/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840850/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73831142/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72815364/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982479/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accept the path parameter as a string and parse it as a CSV. The [request body](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/) is also a good alternative.

I'd recommend using query parameters, they inherently support this behaviour:

```py
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import FastAPI, Query

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(q: Annotated[list[str] | None, Query()] = None):
    query_items = {"q": q}
    return query_items
```

You'd use the path as `/items/q=item_one&q=item_two&q=item_three`.

Here's the relevant [FastAPI Documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values).

Thanks to @11612918 for pointing out an error!

Comment: While I agree this is probably a better solution, query parameters and path parameters are two different things.

Comment: Ah! You're right, thank you. I'll edit my answer.