# Passing a list as a query parameter to FastAPI

Tags: fastapi

I have an endpoint like this:

```
@app.get("/Corr")
async def Corr(symbols : list, sample : str) -> List[CorrItem]:
```

I would like to call it with a list of symbols like this:

```
http://endpoint.com/Corr?symbols=[GOOG, MSFT]&sample=M
```

I am getting a runtime error:

```
HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

Comment: You may also want to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71039241/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840850/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982479/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845425/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75998823/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

The way to send a list in an HTTP request,<sup>*</sup> as described in the [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values) is to send the same query parameter several times:

```
http://endpoint.com/Corr?symbols=GOOG&symbols=MSFT&sample=M
```

<sup>*</sup> There are other ways used in HTTP requests, but this is the one accepted by FastAPI

Comment: Thanks. That got me farther. However with the signature of def Corr as given, I can't call it at runtime. Can you give an example of what the signature of the function looks like?

Comment: `def corr(symbols: List[str], sample: str)`

Comment: @MatsLindh You would need to define the query parameter (i.e., `symbols`) explicitly with `Query`; otherwise, it would be interpreted as a request `body`. Please have a look at the link provided above.