# Pass Array to FastAPI GET endpoint from postman

Tags: list, get, postman, fastapi

I have the following endpoint in FastAPI:

```
@router.get("/", response_model=ApiResponseMultiple[MyObject], response_model_exclude_none=True)
async def get_objs(
    request: Request,
    ids: list
):
    """Get stuffs"""
    print(ids)
...
```

And I cannot get the list to popoulate froma. postman call. I have tried passing the following from postman:

- `1,2`
- `[1,2]`
- `ids=1&ids=2`
- `ids[]=1&ids[]=2`
- `ids[0]=1&ids[1]=2`

[image]

Always my `print` statement spits out `None`.

Comment: FastApi should accept your third option. Try altering the type hint to `list[int]`.

Comment: hmm that didn't work. url looks like this: `/api/?ids=583&ids=584` and type hint is `ids: list[int] = [],`

Comment: In addition to the link provided above, you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71039241/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845425/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73982479/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are sending the paramter `ids` as a list, FastAPI is expecting it as body parameter, and sending body data for GET request is not allowed :)

Modify your code to mark the parameter `ids` explicitly as a query parameter.

Here is a sample:

```py
from fastapi import Query

@router.get("/")
async def get_objs(
    ids: list = Query(...)
):
    """Get stuffs"""
    print(ids)
...
```

Comment: This is close but it makes that param required. How do I make it optional?

Comment: To set a default value, use `Query(default_value)`. So to set `None` as default value, use `Query(None)`. Read more: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/